# Systemctl shows the service as disabled but I can see it running

Tags: systemd, kali-linux, systemctl

I am running kali linux.

When I do `sudo systemctl start ssh` and try to verify with `sudo ss -tlp` I get the following:

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo ss -antlp
State                   Recv-Q                  Send-Q                                   Local Address:Port                                   Peer Address:Port                 Process                                           
LISTEN                  0                       128                                            0.0.0.0:22                                          0.0.0.0:*                     users:(("sshd",pid=12926,fd=3))                  
LISTEN                  0                       128                                               [::]:22                                             [::]:*                     users:(("sshd",pid=12926,fd=4))
```

So the service is running, however if I run `sudo systemctl list-unit-files  | grep ssh` I get the following:

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files  | grep ssh
ssh.service                                                      disabled       
ssh@.service                                                     static         
ssh.socket                                                       disabled       
rescue-ssh.target                                                static  
ssh.socket                                                       disabled
```

So it is not running, what am I missing here:

1. Is `ssh` and `ssh.service` not the same thing ?
2. When I run `sudo systemctl start ssh` am I running a service or something else ?

Comment: After you start ssh (and it *is* a service) what does `systemctl status ssh` return?

Comment: @ajgringo619, it shows `active`, I figured it out, there is a difference between having the service running and having it `enabled`, which is running it automatically at system start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the output of `systemctl list-unit-files`.

My service is running as per `ss -tlp` output, but it is not enabled by default at run time, as shown by `systemctl list-unit-files`.

Running `sudo systemctl enable ssh` marks the service as enabled at start up and the output of `systemcetl list-unit-files` shows that.

Comment: Please note that `systemctl enable X.service` will only trigger the start of the service according to the `[Install]` section. While this in most cases means at startup, this could also be e.g. when a GUI is started, when a user logs in, or upon request by another service (which possibly could only be manually started). Just to make you aware.

Comment: @Fiximan, I wasn't aware of that. thank you!

Comment: @Fiximan, do you know which option in `[Install]` section is determines when the service starts ? I can't find an answer to it here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: All do, you can define multiple dependencies. E.g. `WantedBy=default.target` means "Activate at startup", using `graphical.target`, would activate when a GUI starts, `B.service` means when B is started it is triggered. The `PartOf=B.service` means when B is started or stopped it will be started or stopped, too, `RequiedBy=B.service` means it will be started with B and if it fails, B will fail. Often it's the inverse of using e.g. `Wants=` or `Requires=` in B directly, e.g. if you do not want to alter `B.service` for some reason. Check `special units` for e.g. linking to startup or network.